# Logs for flow execution are not detailed

Tags: community, visual-workflow, debugging, debug-logs, guest-user

I am building a basic public page form on the salesforce communities, creating a 'Property lead' record in our org. By giving edit access to 'Guest User' I can create the records with no problems. I want to check if this lead was already processed earlier and converted to a 'Property' record, but I don't want to give read access on the 'Property' object to the 'Guest User'. I was suggested to use the flow (especially 'auto launched flows') as they run under the system context.

Here is my Flow:

[image: Record Triggered Flow]

Now after the creation of the 'Property Lead' record the flow is firing but not doing the intended update on the 'Property Lead' record if a matching 'Property' record is found.

Here is the finest debug log set on the 'Guest User':
[image: Finest Debug Logs]

As far as I know, the flow is not failing otherwise I would have received a failure email. Is there a way to see the detailed steps happening in the flow and why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of Flow exceptions, it sends to whoever is designated under the Process Automation Settings

`Setup --> Process Automation Settings --> Send Process or Flow Error Email to`

Your two choices are

- User Who Last Modified the Process or Flow
- Apex Exception Email Recipients

I would double check it hasn't been sending to someone else.

---

In terms of debugging, Summer '21 provided [debug Record-Triggered Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_debug_record_triggered_flows.htm&type=5&release=232) (only in non-production orgs). It allows you to do the following

- [Run as another user](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_debug_other_user.htm&type=5&release=228) - `Setup --> Process Automation Settings --> Let Admins debug flows as other users`
- See the highlighted path of where the execution went within your flow
- Get detailed debug details on the right sidebar
- Show Governor Limit Consumption
- Show Transaction Boundaries

When you debug, you can select a record to initiate the flow (for example, the `Property Lead` record that didn't work as expected) and it'll highlight the path it went down and provide the debug details on the right side you're interested in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After changing the 'Let Admins debug flows as other users' to true and debugging the flow under guest user context I was able to pinpoint the problem in the flow.